# Unable to connect to Django with oracle ebs database

Tags: django, python-3.x, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I'm trying to build my first web application using Django.

I'm actually referring to Using Python With Oracle Database 11g (under the section 'Using the Django Framework')

however while trying to execute the command python manage.py runserver i'm getting an error

Steps followed

1. django-admin.py startproject myproj
2. cd myproj
3. python manage.py startapp myapp
4. Once the above commands were executed successfully, the next step was to modify the connection settings to allow the application to connect to the database in the file myproj/settings.py.

Here i updated the details with our database details

```
DATABASES = {

        'default': {

                    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
                    'NAME': '<our ebs database name>',
                    'USER': <username>,
                    'PASSWORD': <password>,

                    }

        }
```

5. Also added the project under the INSTALLED_APPS to associate the application with the project:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [

   'django.contrib.admin',

   'django.contrib.auth',

   'django.contrib.contenttypes',

   'django.contrib.sessions',

   'django.contrib.messages',

   'django.contrib.staticfiles',

   'myproj.myapp'

   ]
   ```
6. In a terminal window when i try to execute the below command from myproj directory:

python manage.py runserver

I'm getting the below error message

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python files\myproj>python manage.py runserver

Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x00000274CA28AEA0>

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 118, in create

```
cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
```

AttributeError: module 'myproj' has no attribute 'myapp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper

```
fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run

```
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception

```
raise _exception[1]
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 337, in execute

```
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper

```
fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup

```
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate

```
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in create

```
import_module(entry)
```

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import

File "", line 983, in _find_and_load

File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproj.myapp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a novice of Django.I think the problem is `myproj.myapp`. You don't need the project name, just add `'myapp',` to INSTALLED_APPS.Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, jutting keeping it to myapp did helped

Answer (score 0):

From the ["Writing your first Django app, part 2: Activating models" tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models):

> To include the app in our project, we need to add a reference to its configuration class in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. The `PollsConfig` class is in the `polls/apps.py` file, so its dotted path is `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'`. Edit the `mysite/settings.py` file and add that dotted path to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. It’ll look like this:
>
> > `mysite/settings.py`¶
> >
> > ```
> > INSTALLED_APPS = [
> >     'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
> >     'django.contrib.admin',
> >     'django.contrib.auth',
> >     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> >     'django.contrib.sessions',
> >     'django.contrib.messages',
> >     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> > ]
> > ```

So look in `myproj/apps.py` and see what the name of the class is and your `INSTALLED_APP` should be something like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'myproj.apps.MyprojConfig'
]
```